# OSX apache permission on external drive with _www group

Tags: macos, apache, permissions

I have an external hard drive connected to my Mac OSX ML box. I wanted to setup a web server to access files on it, but the permission on all files and directories on the drive are "rwx" for the owner which is my local admin, and the group is the "staff" group. I need the files readable by the apache user _www and group _www, I was trying to set all files to be sudo chown -R _www:_www /Volumes/raid_mirror/WebDAV, but this doesn't do anything (gives no errros, just has no effect.) I tried chaning the group using "chgrp" to _www, but that won't work either, it gives me no errors and user and group remain the same.

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 iMac  staff    204 Feb  7 09:54 Download
drwxr-xr-x   5 iMac  staff    170 Feb  5 19:17 STORAGE
drwxr-xr-x   5 iMac  staff    170 Feb  5 19:14 WebDAV
```

Permissions on internal drive with OS look and behave fine:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Jun 20  2012 CGI-Executables
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel   476 Jan 20  2013 Documents
drwxrwxrwx  29 _www  _www    986 Jan 21 12:24 WebDAV
drwxrwxrwx  24 _www  _www    816 Mar 18  2013 WebDAV-Public
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Mac OS X, ownership is disabled by default on external volumes. Make sure that you have enabled ownership for the volume in the Get Info dialog.

The *reverse* of this process is documented in Apple's support document [PH10670: If you don’t have permission to use a disk](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10670). Follow those directions, but turn the specified checkbox **on** instead of off.

Comment: thanks so much, I had read about this but didn't notice it had to be done at the volume level not at the dir level. problem solved!